# When using PyInstaller my dist folder is empty

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

When I use PyInstaller on my .py file it creates an empty dist folder, and when I get this error:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

All help is appreciated! I am running Python 3.7.2, and Windows 10.

I am using the command 'pyinstaller Testing.py' and on the warn-Testing.txt file it says this.

> missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level)
>   missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level)
>   missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (conditional), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level)
>   missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level)
>   excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level)
>   missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level)
>   missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level)
>   missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
>   missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level)
>   missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
>   missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, conditional, optional), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level)
>   missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level), getpass (optional)
>   missing module named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level)
>   missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level)
>   missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed)
>   missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), C:\Users\kayde\PycharmProjects\Testing.py (top-level), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)

Thanks and all help is appreciated! :D

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It will be very hard for people here to help you without some more information. What is the full error traceback (i.e. the error message lines that detail where the error occurred)? And what is the command that you are using to invoke PyInstaller?

Comment: @Xukrao Just added some more info up top, thanks!